# Cannot add Service Reference to my WCF project when it is hosted in IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I've created a WCF service, and have since been developing and testing it by deploying it from Visual Studio 2017 (IIS Express) and adding a service reference to a separate console application in its own solution.

I am ready to begin testing the service over LAN by hosting it through IIS on my computer. However, when adding the service reference, I get the following error message:

*There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:80/Service1.svc/$metadata'.
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost/Service1.svc'.
The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed.
The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.*

I have tried adding things to the Web.config file, but none have proven useful. I have since reverted to the unmodified version of the Web.config file. Can anyone help explain what is going on here?

Comment: Have you tried [this change in the Project Properties tab?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/320c1ffe-17d9-4a6c-903c-9dac724815c0/how-to-configure-wcf-service-on-local-iis?forum=wcf)

Comment: "I am ready to begin testing the service over LAN by hosting it through IIS on my computer." Metadata service can be disabled if you do a proper release. So such error message is desired.  Why do you need to add a service reference when it is hosted on IIS? The wrapper generated earlier should work flawlessly.

Comment: I had tried that. My issue was resolved by enabling HttpActivation in Windows Features. Thanks for your input!